# The complexity of LH restricted to projectors

Tags: complexity-theory, qma

Let's denote $kLP_{c}$ the promise problem where the input, given in an explicit encoding with finite number of bits, is a set $\{p_{1},p_{2},\ldots p_{m}\}$ of k-local projectors over a n-qbits register such that the least eigenvalue $\varepsilon_{\min}$ of $\sum_{i=1}^{m}p_{i}$ is either $\varepsilon_{\min}\leq\varepsilon\tag{y}\label{eq:LHy-1}$ where $\varepsilon$ is a parameter given in input, or $\varepsilon_{\min}(n)\geq\varepsilon+n^{-c}\tag{n}\label{eq:LHn-1}$ and the answer is yes (no) in the \ref{eq:LHy-1} (\ref{eq:LHn-1}) case.

That is, the $k$LH promise problem with hamiltonians that are projectors. Is this restriction known/studied? A circuit->projectors mapping of the type used to prove QMA1-hardness of QSAT should work in mapping to kLP the generic QMA problem. Or one could maybe reduce a kLH instance to an equivalent instance of kLP. However, how would the energy gap behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [standard Kitaev construction](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0210077) yields a Hamiltonian where the individual terms are projectors (up to energy shift & rescaling), each of which constrains the system to a subspace. Thus, the problem is QMA-hard.

Comment: It seems to me that this doesn't (immediately) work for the 2-local reduction [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0406180.pdf)

Comment: @J.Ask Sure, but I have also never talked about that. My answer stands: The problem you are asking about is QMA-hard. And **please don't edit your question afterwards to invalidate existing answers**! **If you have a new question, ask a new question!**

Comment: My edit didn't invalid your answer. I just liked to know if the problem is known/studied also for lower localities than 5. Doesn't seem necessary to open a new question for each k. But if you prefere restate this explicitely for Kitaev's construction and I accept your answer. But I'd like to know about k=2

Comment: @J.Ask It renders my answer incomplete. Regarding k<5, IIRC there is a frustration-free k=3 construction, so this can also be done with projectors. For k=2, one has to see if the perturbation gadgets can be constructed with projectors as well. I would suspect yes, but I am not 100% sure. (Also, note that *any* Hamiltonian can be written as a sum of projectors if you allow several terms to act on the same spins, a perspective of which, if I recall correctly, you are a strong proponent. (Maybe you have to be more precise in stating your question ;p )

Comment: A sum of projectors multiplied by arbitrary constants, not integers

Comment: Might still work, you can approximate any rational. Question is only how good the approximation has to be to not break the normalization of the Hamiltonian vs. gap.

Comment: @J.Ask I'd have to check in detail but I'd bet the paper you link uses perturbation gadgets, where maybe each term in the Hamiltonian is a projector, but they need vastly different prefactors. Though you didn't allow for that.

Comment: The unperturbated hamiltonian is fixed and has the desired form. The perturbation depends on the hamiltonian to be reduced, I'm not able to tell if it is a sum of projectors, probably it is more general. Anyhow if that would work there should be a much easier reduction from the same locality

Comment: In order for it to be perturbative, there have to be terms which are much stronger than others. I've done perturbation gadgets myself ...